# Compute cosine similarity between 3D numpy array and 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, similarity, cosine-similarity

I have a 3D numpy array A of shape (m, n, 300) and a 2D numpy array B of shape (p, 300).

For each of the m (n, 300) matrices in the 3D array, I want to compute its cosine similarity matrix with the 2D numpy array. Currently, I am doing the following:

```
result = []
for sub_matrix in A:
    result.append(sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(sub_matrix, B)
```

The sklearn cosine_similarity function does not support operations with 3D arrays, so is there a more efficient way of computing this that does not involve using the for-loop?

Comment: Wait, so how many outputs do you want in the result. Can you come up with a MCVE at all? You can bypass sklearn and just implement it yourself if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape to `2D` and use the same function -

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

m,n = A.shape[:2]
out = cosine_similarity(A.reshape(m*n,-1), B).reshape(m,n,-1)
```

The output would be `3D` after the reshape at the end, which is what you would get after array conversion of `result`.

Sample run -

```
In [336]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: A = np.random.rand(5,4,3)
     ...: B = np.random.rand(2,3)
     ...: 
     ...: result = []
     ...: for sub_matrix in A:
     ...:     result.append(cosine_similarity(sub_matrix, B))
     ...: out_org = np.array(result)
     ...: 
     ...: from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
     ...: 
     ...: m,n = A.shape[:2]
     ...: out = cosine_similarity(A.reshape(m*n,-1), B).reshape(m,n,-1)
     ...: 
     ...: print np.allclose(out_org, out)
True
```